# c++ opengl draw cylinder using GL_LINE_LOOP

Tags: c++, opengl

So i am trying to replicate a cylinder using a nest for-loop by drawing a series of squares in a circle fashion (check image). This is my code which I need to implement. I know I'm supposed to achieve the four coordinates of each line loop repeatedly until its a circle. I don't know how to calculate the:

-deltaZ

-xLeft

-yLeft

-xRight

-yRight

-thetaRight

Could I get some help? Thanks! (P.S. numSides is at least 3 and numStacks starts out at about 10

```
//Move everything to the z axis
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 2.0);
//change its size so that way its so big
glScalef(0.5, 0.5, 0.0);

float radius = 1.0;
float zTop = 1.0;
float zBottom;
float xLeft;
float yLeft;
float xRight;
float yRight;
float thetaRight;

for (int m = 0; m <= numStacks; m++)
{

  zBottom = zTop-deltaZ;
  xLeft = 0;
  yLeft = 0;
  thetaRight = m*pi/numStacks;
  for (int i=0; i<numSides; i++)
  {
    xRight = 0;
    yRight = 0;
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    //top left
    glVertex3f(xLeft, yLeft, zTop);
    //bottom left
    glVertex3f(xLeft, yLeft, zBottom);
    //bottom right
    glVertex3f(xRight, yRight, zBottom);
    //top right
    glVertex3f(xRight, yRight, zBottom);
    glEnd();

    //exchanging these values moves the
    //line_loop to the right
    xLeft = xRight;
    yLeft = yRight;
    thetaRight = thetaRight + i*pi/numSides;
 }
  zTop = zBottom;
}
```

[image]